# .net core 2.1 test API controller missing AspNetCore.Mvc reference

Tags: c#, xunit, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm trying to tests an API controller with .net core 2.1 as from [this MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

My code looks like

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task ShouldReturnOkWithHealthBackend()
    {
        var apiConsumerService = new Mock<IApiConsumerService>();
        apiConsumerService.Setup(m => m.Consume()).Returns(Task.FromResult(true));

        var controller = new HealthController(apiConsumerService.Object);

        await controller.GetHealth();
    }
```

When doing the await controller method invocation I get stucked with an "Assembly not referenced error"

I can add the

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
```

But VS says that AspNetCore does not exists in the Microsoft namespace.

Intellisense suggests me to add some references but this doesn't work too.

[image: Intellisense suggestions to add AspNetMVC.Core]

But clicking it does nothing. I have also tried to play with the csproj file to see if I can force those assemblies to be loaded but still no success.

I've tested with the XUnit template as well as a custom NUnit project with same results.

My csproj from API and test project are

[image: diff csproj]

What kind of project do I need to create to test a Controller like in the MS doc?

Comment: You should be assigning the result to a variable, to start. Then to Assert

Comment: var result = await controller.GetHealth();

Comment: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing?view=aspnetcore-2.1#testing-controllers

Comment: I'm aware that is still missing the Assert part, but it is irrelevant for this as I cannot invoke any controller method. @joey the docs you're linking are the same I'm refrencing in my question. I haven't been able to see any particular requirement for the solution.

Comment: what is the result after assignign the result to a variable?

Comment: Nothing, as you can see in the attached screenshot, project cannot compile due to missing reference.

Comment: dude, your screenshot does not show you assigning to a variable lol

Comment: made it before adding it. But as said referencing it to a variable makes no difference. Imagine I was trying to only test spectations that internal services are called. Result will be irrelevant

Comment: show a screenshot diff of your csproj file in both the test project and the api project

Comment: @joey added diff for csproj for more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed you didnt bind your project containing the controllers to a version, you should instead do so with the following element.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.1" />
```

You were missing the version!

The devil is in the details. 
If you get a diffent compilation error after updating this element, then you have resolved THIS issue.

Comment: @guillem, if you found the above to resolve your issue, please kindly let us know this answer was useful

Comment: excellent @joey I was wrongly trusting VS to manage my csproj files